# Can't obtain JWT using Resource Owner Flow in Duende

Tags: authentication, jwt, duende

I'm POST'ing to the *token* endpoint using Resource Owner Flow (as [docs explain](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/tokens/password_grant/#requesting-a-token-using-password-grant)), providing the following payload (as [suggested](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/reference/endpoints/token/)).

> client_id:my_client
> client_secret:ShombaBomba
> grant_type:password
> username:my_user
> password:ShombaBomba
> custom-field:custom-value

The error comes back saying the following two things.

> {
> "error": "invalid_grant",
> "error_description": "invalid_username_or_password"
> }

I'm confused, because the user does exist and the password (hashed, of course) is copied from client secrets (where it apparently works). Extra confusion due the info that *invalid grant* is produced (according to [this](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/refresh_tokens.html#requesting-an-access-token-using-a-refresh-token)) when a refresh token is used (i.e. `grant_type_refresh` is present).

I've seen that someone tried to add the grant type `refresh_token` but in my case, it didn't seem to change anything. I had to use a redirect URI for some reason so I hoped the refresh thing was something like that too. But nope...

What can I do to troubleshoot it further? The console says nothing more than that, neither.